# Эффект затемнения вокруг формы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите какие сss надо использовать для затемнение при запуске окна формы 
Вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама форма вот

```css
.modal-window_top{
 font-family: OpenSans-Bold;
 font-size:18px;
 width: 502px;
 height: 56px;
 color:#000;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
}
.close{
 margin-top: -40px;
 margin-right: 17px;
}
.modal-window_bot{
width: 404px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
margin-left: 49px;
margin-top:32px; 
}
.form-control.forma_reg{
margin-top:15px; 
width: 364px;
height: 41px;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.btn.btn_reg{
width: 364px;
height: 41px;
background-color: #333333;
color: #fff;
margin-left: 15px;
border-radius: 0;
}
.btn.btn_reg:hover{
 color: #fff;
}
.help-block.reg_txt{
 font-size:12px ;
 font-family:OpenSans-Regular;
 color:#000;
 float: right;
 clear: right;
 margin-right: 50px;

}
.help-block.reg_txt a{
 font-size:12px ;
 color:#999;
 font-family:OpenSans-Regular;
 text-decoration: underline;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="" style="position: relative;width: 502px;height:350px;background-color:#fff; ">
    <div class="modal-window_top">
     <p style="padding-top:12px; ">ВХОД</p><img src="img/close.png" class="close">
    </div>
     <div class="modal-window_bot">
      <form role="form">
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input  type="email" class="form-control forma_reg" placeholder="E-mail">
       </div>
       </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control forma_reg" placeholder="Пароль">
        </div>
        </div>
        
     <button class="btn btn_reg">ВОЙТИ</button>
      </form></div>
      <p class="help-block reg_txt">У вас ещё нет учетной записи?</p>
        <p class="help-block reg_txt" style="margin-top: -12px;color:#999;"><a href="#">Создать аккаунт</a>/<a href="#">Забыли пароль?</a></p>
    
   </div><!--col-md-6-->
  </div><!--row-->
 </div><!--conta-->
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут есть несколько способов реализации:

1. Сделать подложку во весь экран и поставить ее фоном за слоем с формой.
   Добавить для этого блока:

`background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

2. Для формы добавить значение

`box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`